# Append something to a bash variable that holds output of commands

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

This-

```
$a=`ls` | do something | etc. | etc. | etc...
echo "$a"
```

gives this-

```
file1
file2
file3
```

But I want to append something to the end of that variable, so I tried

```
a=${a}\nfile4
```

But I get this-

```
file1
file2
file3nfile4   # wrong!
```

Comment: can you try with echo : `a=$(echo -e "${a}\nfile")`

Comment: @SivaPrasath WORKS! Pls add as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: in a more general note, you should use `$()` instead of ``

Comment: @Kiwy why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Bash, you can append to a variable using `var+=value`. But your problem isn't that, but in generating the newline. The easiest way is to use `$'..'` quoting, which interprets backslash-escapes like `\n` for newline:

```
a+=$'\nfile4'
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is to get the listing of files in the current directory and then append a string to each of these names:

```
set -- *
printf '%s-somestring\n' "$@"
```

or, using a `bash` array,

```
names=( * )
printf '%s-somestring\n' "${names[@]}"
```

Using an array, either the array of positional parameters (the first example above, which will work in all POSIX shells), or a `bash` array, is the safest way to work with filenames. If you are converting the filenames into some sort of delimited string, then you will run into issues when you have filenames containing whatever character you have chosen to delimit the string with.

To *only append something to the end of the output*, do that in a separate `echo`:

```
# code that output something
# then,
echo 'additional data'
```

Or, modifying my examples from above:

```
set -- * 'additional data'
printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

and

```
names=( * 'additional data' )
printf '%s\n' "${names[@]}"
```

Or...

```
set -- *
set -- "$@" 'additional data'
printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

and

```
names=( * )
names+=( 'additional data' )
printf '%s\n' "${names[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try with echo :

```
a=$(echo -e "${a}\nfile")
```